# Java Regular Expression removing everything but numbers from String

Tags: java, regex

I have two strings
`string1 = 44.365 Online order`
and `string2 = 0 Request Delivery`. Now I would like to apply a regular expression to these strings that filters out everything but numbers so I get integers like `string1 = 44365` and `string2 = 0`.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 79, accepted):

You can make use of the `^`. It considers everything apart from what you have infront of it.

So if you have `[^y]` its going to filter everything apart from y. In your case you would do something like

```
String value = string.replaceAll("[^0-9]","");
```

where string is a variable holding the actual text!

Comment: `\D` would 67% shorter as a pattern. ;)

Comment: Yes but far less efficient.

Comment: @DaMainBoss how to include negative numbers also? I mean, I have to replace everything that is not a positive/negative number with an empty space. How to do that?

Comment: @PankajSinghal negative numbers start with `-` so something like `[^-?0-9]` should do the trick. `-?` there tells the regex engine to match `-` if it exists(0 or none).

Answer (score 28):

```
String clean1 = string1.replaceAll("[^0-9]", "");
```

or

```
String clean2 = string2.replaceAll("[^\\d]", "");
```

Where `\d` is a shortcut to `[0-9]` character class, 
or

```
String clean3 = string1.replaceAll("\\D", "");
```

Where `\D` is a negation of the `\d` class (which means `[^0-9]`)

Answer (score 10):

```
string1 = string1.replaceAll("[^0-9]", "");
string2 = string2.replaceAll("[^0-9]", "");
```

Answer (score 3):

> This is the [Google Guava #CharMatcher](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/CharMatcher.html) Way.

```
String alphanumeric = "12ABC34def";

String digits = CharMatcher.JAVA_DIGIT.retainFrom(alphanumeric); // 1234

String letters = CharMatcher.JAVA_LETTER.retainFrom(alphanumeric); // ABCdef
```

> If you only care to match ASCII digits, use

```
String digits = CharMatcher.inRange('0', '9').retainFrom(alphanumeric); // 1234
```

> If you only care to match letters of the Latin alphabet, use

```
String letters = CharMatcher.inRange('a', 'z')
                         .or(inRange('A', 'Z')).retainFrom(alphanumeric); // ABCdef
```