# How do I get only integers from a string?

Tags: java

I have a text field where someone can enter a string.

But I need to return an integer using that string.

I know how to convert strings to integers, but how do I separate any letters & punctuation from the string so it leaves only numbers?

Comment: First you'll need some code

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2):

Try this code:

```
String str = "a1?2.33/4tyz.7!8x";
str = str.replaceAll("\\D", "");
```

Now `str` will contain `"1233478"`

Answer (score 0):

Match against regular expression. 0-9

Example has been given before.
[How to extract numbers from a string and get an array of ints?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2367381/extract-numbers-from-a-string-java)

Answer (score 0):

You could replace all extra symbols with regular expression ant then call `Integer.valueOf()`.
For example:

```
Integer.valueOf(src.replaceAll("[!0-9]",""));
```

Comment: should it be [^0-9] ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace all the values you don't want in your string and then parse the rest as an integer:

```
    String userInput = "Number 42 is the best";
    userInput = userInput.replaceAll("[^\\d]", '');
    return Integer.parseInt(test); //returns '42'
```

There is an existing post similar on how to do this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6883579/java-regular-expression-removing-everything-but-numbers-from-string)